# Can I use Tailwind's media query variants in PostCSS?

Tags: tailwind-css, postcss

Tailwind provides [responsive utility variants](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design) `sm`, `md`, `lg`, `xl` and `2xl`, and you can [define your own](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/screens) as well.

I can use them in class names:

```html
<img class="w-16 md:w-32" src="...">
```

But can I also use them in PostCSS?

For example, I'm hoping to do something like this (the code doesn't actually work):

```css
img {
  @apply w-16;

  /* I want this section to apply whenever the `md` media query applies. */
  md:& {
    @apply w-32;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do it with [@screen](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors#nesting) directive or [screen()](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#screen) function

```css
img {
  @apply w-16;

  @screen md {
    @apply w-32;
  }
}

img {
  @apply w-16;

  @media screen(md) {
    @apply w-32;
  }
}
```

Sometimes Tailwind may yelling about not supported nested syntax (depends on your PostCSS config or [Preprocessor like Less](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors#less)) so you may change code a little

```css
img {
  @apply w-16;
}

@screen md {
 img {
   @apply w-32;
 }
}
```

Finally nothing stops you from using variants within `@apply` if you wish

```css
img {
  @apply w-16 md:w-32;
}
```

Comment: is thera a PostCSS config that works with nested media queries and Tailwind @apply?